# setText() with com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle , how do I fix it?

Tags: android

I meet a matter with the `btn.setText()`, but it can `setOnClickListener()` 
the logcat tell me :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.gc.materialdesign.views.Button.setText(Button.java:185)

I try to fix but fail,
This is the .java code:

```
package com.example.rain.fishingcard;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle startbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startbtn = (com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);

    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            startbtn.setText("I like");
        }
    });
}
}
```

and it is the .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.rain.fishingcard.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fishing Card!"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/startText" />

<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
    android:id="@+id/startbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1E88E5"
    android:text="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/startText" />

<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
    android:id="@+id/settingbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1E88E5"
    android:text="setting"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startbtn"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startbtn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/startbtn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is the logcat:

```
  06-19 00:26:23.627 2130-2130/com.example.rain.fishingcard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
  main Process: com.example.rain.fishingcard, PID: 2130
  Theme: themes:{}
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.gc.materialdesign.views.Button.setText(Button.java:185)
    at com.example.rain.fishingcard.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
    at com.gc.materialdesign.views.Button.makeCircle(Button.java:135)
    at com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle.onDraw(ButtonRectangle.java:145)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15184)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15144)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15144)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15144)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15144)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15144)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15144)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:282)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:288)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:323)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2623)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2075)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 06-19 00:31:23.342 2130-2130/com.example.rain.fishingcard I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2130 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code from :

```
 startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            startbtn.setText("I like");
        }
    });
```

To the code:

```
 startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            TextView textButton = new TextView(getContext());
            textButton.setText("I like");
            startbtn.setText(textButton);
        }
    });
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: I try your advice, but it still fail,       
     Error:(27, 52) 错误: 找不到符号
符号: 方法 getContext()
     Error:(29, 34) 错误: 不兼容的类型: TextView无法转换为String

Comment: And I also use the 

    TextView textButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startText);

to replace the textButton in your code, it still fail

    Error:(29, 34) 错误: 不兼容的类型: TextView无法转换为String

it seems that there is a  wrong variable type to the fiction

Answer (score 0):

just try to download library and import it as a module in your app, then try to replace two classes ButtonRectangle.java and ButtonFlat.java with this two classes [ButtonRectangle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9br4izbehd7rnk/ButtonRectangle.java?dl=0) and [ButtonFlat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/86lc52blvuhl02e/ButtonFlat.java?dl=0) then you are good to go.